# Cmake cannot find package config file from vcpkg

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to write `CMakeLists.txt` for my game but I have a problem using `find_package`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.0)
project(pong)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_mixer CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2main)

file(GLOB SOURCES source/*.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${WIN32_GUI} ${SOURCES})
```

On the `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` line, cmake stops and throws an error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSDL2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2" with any of
  the following names:

    SDL2Config.cmake
    sdl2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SDL2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SDL2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SDL2"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I tried adding these lines but it doesn't help

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
include (C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x86-windows")
```

Everything is fine on the vcpkg side. SDL2 installed, `vcpkg integrate install` used

UPD:
I moved `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")` to the beginning `CMakeLists.txt` and now it throws this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:852 (_find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "SDL2" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/share/sdl2/SDL2Config.cmake, version: 2.26.5 (32bit)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

Comment: `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` where exactly in your CMakeLists.txt file did you put this?

Comment: @starball after `project(pong)`

Comment: try putting it before the call to `project`, or specifying on commandline as a cache variable with [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D)

Comment: @starball already. But the problem remained. Updated the question, the output is there

Comment: Why do you have VCPKG installed in `C:/Program Files`? I hope you are not running builds with Administrator rights. Move VCPKG to a different location.

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried moving vcpkg to C:/ but the error hasn't changed since the first UPD

Comment: Um, I changed `set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x86-windows")`to `set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-windows")` and it worked. But what about x86? I have both versions of installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) This is a duplicate of another stack overflow question which I answered and cannot find currently

b) This is a common error. Your CMake Generator is `x64` (Probably `Visual Studio 2022` which defaults to `x64`) while your `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` is `x86`. CMake won't allow to mix x64 and x86. Use `x64-windows` for your `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` or switch the CMake Generator to be `x86`

Comment: I added `set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM "x86")` and it worked